# I/O Complexity Analysis with Memory Hierarchies

Tags: algorithms, optimization, computer-architecture, runtime-analysis, memory-hierarchy

How to go about analysing the I/O complexity when there are multiple levels of memory involved? Looking up I/O complexity analyses returns papers such as [this one](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/48529.48535), which generally assume for simplicity that the memory is just two-level (disk and cache).

Comment: What memory levels do you mean?

Comment: Anything over two-level. Looking for pointers to analyses of I/O complexities with >2 levels. (Most machines I've used are 3 cache levels + DRAM + disk, for instance, but I'm not looking for analyses of any particular kinds of hierarchies)

Comment: oh, you mean cpu caches. I/O devices, or rather DMA engines, can't access CPU caches, so any data to be exchanged is flushed from caches to RAM.